# Can mremap place mappings at 0?

Tags: linux, null, posix, mmap

According to both the [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html#NOTES) and the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html), `mmap` will not place new mappings at address 0 so long as the `MAP_FIXED` flag isn't provided.

Is the same true for Linux's [`mremap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html)? The man page description for the `REMAP_FIXED` flag says that it "serves a similar purpose to the MAP_FIXED flag of mmap(2)," but doesn't explicitly say that, if it's not present, `mremap` is guaranteed to not place the mapping at 0.

Is this guarantee actually made? If so, is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

No, Linux `mremap` will not place mappings at address 0.  Most systems will not even do this if `MREMAP_FIXED` is specified.

Comment: Do you have documentation to back this up?